# Change matrixblock field value before save element

Tags: craft3, matrix, modules, saveentry

So i have a Matrix with one type of matrixblocks.

These all have a field for a custom id which should be set by the system, if empty, before the entry is saved.

I can access the individual matrixblocks and change the field value in all of them. But i am not sure how to add them back to the matrix so the changes will apply.

example code that is not working:
[image]

Comment: Where do you use this code? In a module? If so it would help to know which event you hook to, if any, or if it's in a controller action. Have you tried `$execution->save()`?

Comment: I am using this code inside a module. It is triggered inside the EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT Event.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of testing, it appears you don't have anything to do to have your values saved, just set them and Craft will take care of the rest.

```
    Event::on(
        Elements::class,
        Elements::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT,
        static function (ElementEvent $event) {
            $element = $event->element;
            if ($element instanceof Entry && $element->getSection()->handle === 'testSection') {
                /** @var MatrixBlock[] $blocks */
                $blocks = $element->getFieldValue('testMatrix')->all();
                foreach ($blocks as $block) {
                    $block->setFieldValue('automaticField', uniqid('some unique value', false));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I implemented it the same way as you but the changes were not applied and not shown in the ControlPanel edit page.

Comment: Okey so i handled my problem for the after save in another way.
But would you know how to save it in, lets say, a controller? Getting the element via an id , then change the field value of certaint matrix blocks and then resave it?

Comment: Not tested but I guess you could just call the `save()` method on the element after making your changes. But if my previous code example didn't work for you, I'm afraid just calling `save()` might not be enough. Can you explain what you did in the after save?

Comment: This irritates me. A `save()` function on MatrixBlocks does not exist for me. Or are we both talking about different things?

After Save:
We are now generating and saving a custom id on the element. If the custom id of each matrix block is needed, a combination from the element's custom id and the matrix block id is generated inside a simple sevice.

Comment: I'm talking about the `save()` method on the element owning the matrix field (this is most probably an Entry).